# HDFS behavior when removing a DataNode directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I setup a Hadoop cluster (HDP 2.6) which contains of 3 nodes with the following HDFS mounting points on each node.

- /mnt/datadisk1
- /mnt/datadisk2
- /mnt/datadisk3

So, my `/etc/fstab` file looks like this on each of the three nodes:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
...
# Here the HDFS Partitions:
/dev/sdb                /mnt/datadisk1          xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc                /mnt/datadisk2          xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdd                /mnt/datadisk3          xfs     defaults        0 0
```

The paths are also set in the HDFS config (Ambari) `dfs.datanode.data.dir = /mnt/datadisk1,/mnt/datadisk2,/mnt/datadisk3`.

My question is now: What would happen, if I would remove e.g. `/mnt/datadisk3` from **one** of my Hadoop nodes? Would the HDFS be rebalanced and the data that was on this partition re-replicated? Would the `/mnt/datadisk3` partition on the **other** nodes still be usable?

Each partition has a size of ~1 TB. Would my HDFS afterwards have `3*1TB + 3*1TB + 2*1TB = 8TB` or maybe only `2*1TB + 2*1TB + 2*1TB = 6TB` (because all `datadisk3` partitions would be removed from the HDFS)?

Answer (score 0):

- If you remove or won't mention the path of

  ```
  dfs.datanode.data.dir =/mnt/datadisk1,/mnt/datadisk2,/mnt/datadisk3

  dfs.datanode.data.dir = /mnt/datadisk1,/mnt/datadisk2
  ```

  their won't be any connection with datadisk3,so datadisk3 data no more  available.
- Yes , HDFS be rebalance  the data that was on respective partition and replicate it into other block(based on your replication factor).
- no you can't use data that is stored in datadisk3 (if you are using commissioning and decommissioning method then  only you can reuse the data)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 nodes and you have deleted one. this means there are 2 nodes left and each node contains same data since replication factor is 2, but your data will be there but with only two replicas